# change z-index of another element on hover

Tags: html, css

I have html like this:

```
<div class="projectThumb">
    <div class="textContainer">
        <h1>Header1</h1>
        <h2>&#9642 Header2a &#9642 Header2b &#9642</h2>
    </div>                  
    <a class="project1 video" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxx?transparent=0"><img src="Thumbnails/project1.png"></a>
</div>
```

Clicking the `<a>` tags with `class="video"` trigger a JS plugin that opens a video player within the page.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.projectThumb img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
   -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
   -o-transform: scaleY(1);
   -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
   transform: scaleY(1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.projectThumb img:hover {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0.2)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0.2);
   opacity: 0.2;
}
```

When you hover over the `<img>` within the `<a>` (which takes up the whole `projectThumb`), the `<img>` opacity decreases revealing the text, but the image still bleeds through the text because the image is still on top of it. Is there a way to change the `z-index` of one of the elements to avoid having it bleed through? I've tried adding the following to CSS:

```
.projectThumb a:hover {
    z-index: -999;
}
```

I've also tried adding `z-index` to `.projectThumb img:hover` like this:

```
.projectThumb img:hover {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0.2)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0.2);
   opacity: 0.2;
   z-index: -999;
}
```

Neither work. I can bring the text to the front by setting the `z-index` of `.textContainer h1, .textContainer h2, .textContainer h3`, which does bring the text to the front, but I don't know how to trigger that on `projectThumb img:hover` so that it's only on top of the image on hover. I'd also like the entire `<div>` to remain clickable, even the text portion. When I bring the text to the front using `z-index`, the text area isn't clickable because it's on top of the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its anywhere else in the CSS but I don't see any positioning.
In order for z-indexing to work you need to have some sort of position set.

Add position: relative to any of the classes you want to apply z-indexing to.

```
.projectThumb a, .projectThumb img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I think this is part of my problem. I added `position: relative;` to `.projectThumb img` and added `z-index: -999;` to `.projectThumb img:hover`. This caused flickering on hover. The `<div>` container, `.projectThumb`, has a yellow background, so I tried setting `.projectThumb img:hover` to `z-index: -998;` and `.projectThumb:hover` to `z-index: -999;` but this didn't work either. Any thoughts on what my issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `z-index` for that, you may use variables:

```
:root {
    --thumbIndex: 0;
}

.projectThumb {
    z-index: var(--thumbIndex);
}

a:hover {
    --thumbIndex: -999;
}
```

I think thou, better idea will be to use the `display` property instead.